# call ajax after clicking button on colorbox

Tags: ajax, jquery, colorbox

I am getting following error on firefox(version : 14.0.1) ,when I am calling ajax after clicking on button that is present on colorbox.

Error : `NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument`

Below is my code : 
following function get called ,when i click on a button.

```
function addIdentifierManually(moduleName, pageNumber){
    $.colorbox({
        html : "<strong>"+moduleName+" :</strong><input class='text "+moduleName+"Text' id='identifier' value=''>"
               +"<br/><br/><center><input type='button' value='Insert' onclick='insertIdentifier("+moduleName+","+pageNumber+")'/></center>",
        width : '300px',
        height : '200px',

    });
}
```

In html of above color box , here is a button and onclick function on click event.
Button is clicked by user when he enter his input in text field.

```
function insertIdentifier(moduleName, pageNumber){
    var data ={
            moduleName : moduleName,
            pageNumber : pageNumber

    };

    $.ajax({
        url : "addIdentifierManually.htm",
        dataType : "text",
        type : "POST",
        data : data,

        success : function(data){

        },

        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Where I am missing? Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
function addIdentifierManually(moduleName, pageNumber) {
    $.colorbox({
        html : "<strong>"+moduleName+" :</strong><input class='text "+moduleName+"Text' id='identifier' value=''>"
               +"<br/><br/><center><input type='button' value='Insert' id='insertIdent' /></center>",
        width : '300px',
        height : '200px',

    });

    $("#insertIdent").bind('click', insertIdentifier(moduleName,pageNumber));
}
```

Comment: You are not 100 % right. u'r solution doesn't wait for user input.When color box open ,it just fire ajax.

But you give me direction,that solved my problem.

$("#insertIdent").bind('click', function(){
  insertIdentifier(moduleName,pageNumber,$('#insertIdent').val());
 });